# Google piecharts slice text alignment issue in chrome 31

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-visualization

In chrome version 31, When you take a look at the [Google piechart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart) the numbers and text are placed poorly, often off of the slice on the larger slices. "German" becomes "Ger" and "45%" becomes "45" .

2.I put the below code for solving the issue.

```
if(window.navigator.appVersion.match(/Chrome\/(31.*?) /)) { // fix for chrome v31
    var pie_text = jQuery('#all-receivers-pie-chart g text');
    var chrome_fix = jQuery(pie_text[1]).attr('x') - 30; //it's the second one causing the problem, move it to the left 30px
    jQuery(pie_text[1]).attr('x',chrome_fix); 
}
```

3.With the above code the text is positioned correctly when the page loads. But when I mouse over on the chart the tooltip comes and the pie chart slice text takes back the original poor position.

4.Also when the values are less for any field say 2.46% or so, there will be no text field for that and the code above wont work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a `onmouseout` event handler to call that code when the user mouses out of a chart element:

```
// assuming you have a function called "fixLabelAlignmentInChrome"
google.visualization.events.addListener(myPieChart, 'onmouseout', fixLabelAlignmentInChrome);
```